# Error: "Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

I'm getting this error message while trying to create a database using Code first, using the command "add-migration" in .Net:

''' `An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Failed to load configuration from file 'C:\Users\Jezus PC\Desktop\BulkyBookWeb\BulkyBook\BulkyBookWeb\appsettings.json'. Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728`

Comment: Does the file exist?

Comment: The question is hard to read. Would you mind to fix the title, move the command and the error output into code blocks of type batch, and check the grammar a little? I would do the edition myself but the queue seems to be full already. Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming the problem has been resolved, however for me, it was a "," missing from the appsetting.json file.